# Creating a fast relational db with billions of rows

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have thousands of IoT sensors writing to a table in a MySQL DB. I have 10s of millions of rows and it is running fine. I am about to expand and would like advice on how I can adjust the db to have a longer life with many more records.

Current Table

```
CREATE TABLE `sensor_data` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s6` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s3_analog` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `long` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batterylife` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cell_dbm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ccid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imei` bigint(15) NOT NULL,
  `fullget` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `build_version` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `location` (`location`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `imei` (`imei`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=111111111111 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Exmple of values

```
#...,111,111,111,111.22,1111,11,11.22,1111111111111,lat,long,11,-11,11111111111111111111a,long-url,1.22,timestamp
```

This is my plan, please let me know where I am wrong and how I can improve the setup.

I am sure you can see things wrong with this table already, and that's why I want to break it up.

So the main issue I see in the future is that I am joining lots of other tables to this table to show reports hourly. I connect the other queries to the `location` and order by the `timestamp`.

I only need to read the `s1-s6` readings and this is the table breakout I was thinking.

`sensor_readings`
id,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6

`sensor_link_data` <- this table would have the most lookups
id,sensor_reading_id,location,imei,timestamp

`sensor_additional_data` <- not used a lot, but useful to troubleshoot
id,sensor_reading_id,lat,long,batterylife,ccid,fullget,build_version

So the main question is, is this dumb and I should keep it all in one table since I only have 18 columns or will it be very useful to break it up?

Server Info

Xeon E3-1230 v6 Quad-Core 3.5 GHz 1

- ECC DDR4 SDRAM (16 GB)
- 480 GB Enterprise SSD 1
- 480 GB Enterprise SSD 1
- 4 Port RAID Card (SATA) 1
- 1 Gbps Uplink Port Speed

--- UPDATE ---

Thank you for your info, sincerely.

Here is what I have come up with, if you see anything obviously wrong please advise.

```
CREATE TABLE `sensor_readings` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s1` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s2` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s3` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s3_analog` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s4` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s5` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s6` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imei` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bat_life` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `recorded` (`imei`,`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `imei` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `build_version` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cell_dbm` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imei`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Nearly every column is a VARCHAR.  How many bytes is your average record?  You can think about moving your database to Oracle or DB2 on bigger servers to gain performance.

Comment: Sorry for not including that, I added the example of what is in each field.

Comment: So, the sensor data stored in columns s1 to s6 are non-numeric?  In almost all instances, sensors return information such as temperature, pressure, or some other numeric value measured by the sensor.  Storing that data as a string (i.e. `varchar`) is incredibly inefficient.  You said you added sample data to your question, but it's not clear which columns the data belongs to.  Please take a look at [mcve] and add actual sample data from your table to the question.

Comment: Okay, sorry I am not good at this, thank you for responding. The numbers are in order below the table. So they are all whole or double decimal place numbers.

Comment: `DOUBLE` (8 bytes, 16 significant digits) is rarely needed for sensor data.  Consider `FLOAT` (4 bytes, 7 significant digits) instead.  For a billion rows, that would save 4GB per column changed.  Such a change will help achieve "fast".

Comment: I wonder what the difference between s3 and s3_analog is.  And why you need both.

Comment: Hello again Rick. s3 is a pressure sensor, they can use a 0-100, 0-200, 0-2000 sensor, if the config file on the device has the wrong sensor marked the s3 will be incorrect. If I have the analog I can make an exception for that device and I can use the analog math to correct for it.

Answer (score 1):

Either "normalize" the `VARCHARs` or convert to numeric or rethink whether they belong in `sensor_data`.  I assume `sensor_data` will have millions or billions of rows.

By converting to numeric, I am referring to anything that is inherently numeric (volts, velocity, temp, etc).  Be sure to pick the smallest representation for each value.  For example, "1.2" stored in `VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8` will take 5 bytes, but `DECIMAL(4,2)` will need only 2 bytes.

"Imei" -- and "cell..." -- are you monitoring cellphones?  Move any static info from `sensor_data` to a `phones` table, which will include static things like `build_version`.  `JOIN` to `phones` via `imei`.

Lat/lng could probably be a pair of 4-byte `FLOATs` if 1.7m / 5.6 ft is adequate precision.  (See https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices for more suggestions.)

`PRIMARY KEY(imei, timestamp)` is probably a better PK, and get rid of `id`.

There is no `HASH` indexing; `BTree` is just as fast anyway.

If you intend to purge "old" data, [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) the table.

An approach to saving a lot of disk space is to summarize the data and toss the raw data.  See [*Summary Tables*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Still more in my 'under construction' sensor blog:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor

If the sensors always have a value, declare them `NOT NULL`.

Comment: In my opinion the best choice for lat and lon is the signed medium int, where each value is multiplied by 40000 and rounded, to rid of floating point calculations. Say, N51.23456 becomes 2049382 and S65.43210 becomes -2617284. In the worst case deviation will be no more than 2.5m.

Comment: This is great information! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I think I used your info to the best of my understanding and have updated the original question with the 2 new tables. Please take a look and let me know your thoughts. Happy New Year

Comment: @Matt - Is there a reason for the sensor columns being `NULLable`?

Comment: Hi Rick, not all sensors are on each device so some have 3 sensors and some have 6. Am I doing that incorrectly?

Comment: @Matt - OK, Having them NULLable is OK.